# Twitter Enterprise API

Tags: javascript, api, twitter

I am trying to request data from an endpoint in the twitter enterprise API (/totals)

I have been successfull in retrieving data from /historical using oauth 1.0a

And to my eye the response I get from the authorization looks correct

```
{
    "statusCode": 403,
    "body": {
        "errors": [
            "Forbidden to access tweets: 123456789,
        ]
    },
    "headers": {
        "date": "Tue, 10 Aug 2021 12:17:56 GMT",
        "server": "tsa_o",
        "set-cookie": [
            "personalization_id=\"XXXXXXX/xxxxxx==\"; Max-Age=63072000; Expires=Thu, 10 Aug 2023 12:17:57 GMT; Path=/; Domain=.twitter.com; Secure; SameSite=None",
            "guest_id=v1%3A162859787755489778; Max-Age=63072000; Expires=Thu, 10 Aug 2023 12:17:57 GMT; Path=/; Domain=.twitter.com; Secure; SameSite=None"
        ],
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "x-request-id": "8db9ed7b269fe772",
        "cache-control": "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0",
        "content-length": "189",
        "content-encoding": "gzip",
        "strict-transport-security": "max-age=631138519",
        "x-connection-hash": "3581ca69fa8583875f011a335e831ea0e9a1e6fbe14f2fb37d473825116bea23",
        "connection": "close"
    },
    "request": {
        "uri": "https://data-api.twitter.com/insights/engagement/totals",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip",
            "accept": "application/json",
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "content-length": 424,
            "Authorization": "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"XXXXXXXXXXxxxxx\",oauth_nonce=\"xXXXXXX\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_timestamp=\"1628597877\",oauth_token=\"xxxxxxxXXXXXXX\",oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_signature=\"xXXXXXXXXXX\""
        }
    }
}
```

Code:

```
Authorization code below, 
  async getRequest({ oauth_token, oauth_token_secret }, params) {
    const oAuthConfig = {
      consumer_key: "xx",
      consumer_secret: "xx",
      token: oauth_token,
      token_secret: oauth_token_secret,
    }
    
    const req = await post({
      url: new URL(
        "https://data-api.twitter.com/insights/engagement/totals"
      ),
      headers: { "Accept-Encoding": "gzip" },
      oauth: oAuthConfig,
      body: params,
      json: true,
      gzip: true,
    })
    if (req.body) {
      return req.body
    } else {
      throw new Error("Cannot get an OAuth request token")
    }
  }
This method is then called as per docs with the information needed, however as you can see from the output I get Forbidden to access tweets,

  async getMetrics(tweet_ids, info, oldest) {
    const accessToken = {
      oauth_token: info.tokens.accessToken,
      oauth_token_secret: info.tokens.refreshToken,
      user_id: info.id,
      screen_name: info.username,
    }
    
    try {
        let params = {
        tweet_ids: tweet_ids,
        engagement_types: [
            "impressions", 
            "engagements", 
            // "favorites", 
            // "retweets", 
            // "quote_tweets", 
            // "replies", 
            // "video_views"
        ],
        groupings: {
          "types-by-tweet-id": {
            group_by: [
              "tweet.id",
              "engagement.type",
            ],
          },
        },
      }
      
      const response = await this.getRequest(accessToken, params)
      console.log(response)
      if (response.hasOwnProperty("errors")) {
        if (response.unavailable_tweet_ids) {
        }
        throw response.errors
      }
      return response
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
      throw e
    }
  }
```

I am at a total loss to why this is not working, as it works like I described with the /historical endpoint, can anyone spot the error in the authentication code as per docs Forbidden access means per docs that there is something wrong with the authentication
Docs: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/enterprise/engagement-api/api-reference/post-insights-engagement#errors

Comment: What exactly is `post()`? One basic thing you can try is `body: JSON.stringify(params)` because depending on what exactly is making the request, you might have to provide actual JSON as the POST body.

Comment: @ChrisG the question is not about semantics I was looking for someone who had worked with the twitter enterprise API before that might have some clarity on the authentication used, the body is correct and does not need to be stringified.

Comment: Is it possible that `tweet_ids` contains ids of tweets that aren't owned?

Comment: @ChrisG I am afraid this is not the case